# Where should I specify the output_field kwarg in this complex query?

Tags: django

I wrote a little survey app. I have a query that causes an exception upon upgrade to Django 2.0:

> Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.

Here's a few relationships necessary to understand the query (where `--fk-->` indicats a foreign key):

```
response --fk--> question --fk--> survey
response --fk--> person
```

Here's my query:

```
answered_surveys = SurveyResponse.objects.all()\
    .values('fk_question__fk_survey__hash', 'fk_question__fk_survey__name')\
    .annotate(
        nb_respondants = Count('fk_person', distinct=True),
        survey_name = F('fk_question__fk_survey__name'),
        survey_hash = F('fk_question__fk_survey__hash')
    )\
    .annotate(
        completion=100*Count('id')/
        (F('nb_respondants')*F('fk_question__fk_survey__nb_questions_per_survey'))
    )
```

It's fine up until the last `annotate`, but I don't know where to add the `output_field` kwarg since I only have `F` and `Count` models. `Count` outputs an IntegerField by definition, F complains if I try to add that kwarg.

How do I fix this?

Comment: this [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24485) might help you

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what it was. Cool to see the historical context behind that feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Gahan's comment, I discovered I need to use an `ExpressionWrapper` to perform arithmetic on F objects within an annotation. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

The last part hence becomes:

```
.annotate(
    completion=ExpressionWrapper(
        100*Count('id')\
        (F('nb_respondants')*F('fk_question__fk_survey__nb_questions_per_survey')),
    output_field=FloatField()
)
```